# Laravel Eloquen Eager Loading issue on Ubuntu 20.4 with MariaDB need some insight

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, eloquent, mariadb

This sounds weird but suddenly the eager loading method on our production system stops working completely out of nowhere (no recent server/application update or something). Temporarily I have converted the application to either use Lazy Loading or Manual Eager Loading for the application to work properly.

I am using the following on our machine:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.4
- DB: 10.3.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Framework:
- Laravel 5.4

Issue:

All block of code that involves the 'with' method on our eloquent query ALWAYS return an empty collection

```
Table::with('relationTable')->get();
```

It doesnt return any exception, it just always return blank collection on every table that uses the 'with' method.

This one works without issue btw

```
$records = Table::first();
$records->relationTable;
```

Here are some stuff that I've isolated so far

1. Dump the database and load it to windows mysql = App works normally
2. Dump the database and load it to Ubuntu 18 mariadb = App works normally
3. Dump the database and load it to Ubuntu 20 mariadb = App doesnt work
4. Connect a local app with a remote database running on Ubuntu 20 = App doesnt work
5. Connect a local app with a remote database running on Ubuntu 18 - App works normally

So based from that, I can assume that the app has nothing to do with it and it might one of the following

1. OS
2. Driver
3. Database

While I do have a solution already (Migrate the app to Ubuntu 18), I want to know WHAT is causing this issue. Tried checking db logs and etc and it seems that the query is OK and no errors are being detected. Also tried changing database configure like table_cache settings still to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

So I had a very similar issue to what you're describing above today too. I'm using MariaDB 10.3.34, and after spending several hours digging through code, I noticed that if the prepared statement has 1000 or more prepared parameters within the IN() statement, then it fails.

Laravel Eager/Lazy loading will then grab the information from the primary table and search the relation table using an IN(). I hit the 999 limit earlier today when suddenly loads of things just stopped working. Took a while to find this all out because using debugbar the actual sql works perfectly fine.

I'm not getting this issue with 10.3.27 or 10.3.31. I haven't tested any other 10.3.xx versions of MariaDB yet. If you can downgrade MariaDB to 10.3.31 that should fix your problem.